# kogito task management API throwing 500 exception while querying completed tasks when process instance is still OPEN

Tags: kogito

kogito task management rest API (GET/POST) (/api/workflow/{processInstanceId}/{task_name}/{taskId}) is throwing HTTP 500 exception  when respective task is already completed but process instance is still OPEN

excepting kogito APIs should throw HTTP 409 (or) any HTTP 4XX exception when task is not found/task is completed irrespective of process instance is completed or not.
throwing HTTP 500 exception is seems to be inappropriate and would lead to confusion.

any leads on this issue would certainly help me further.

Answer (score 0):

Opened https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-8925 to fix this. There is an exception that is not properly mapped to 404 error code.